# Issue with accessing JSON file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Here is my test.json file

```
{
"pageTitle": "Test Page",
"firstName": "Matt"
}
```

Here is how I'm accessing it in my JS file

```
var jsonObj = {};
var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxReq.overrideMimeType("application/json");
ajaxReq.open('GET', 'path/to/file/test.json', true);
ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    if (ajaxReq.readyState == 4) 
    {
        jsonObj = ajaxReq.responseText;
        alert(jsonObj.pageTitle);
    }
}
ajaxReq.send(null);
```

But when I run the script the alert box says 'undefined'.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I've been working at this for a couple hours now and can't seem to find the answer.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have to parse the JSON, or it will just be a string.

Comment: I tried doing JSON.parse(ajaxReq.responseText) and FireBug threw an error saying 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character' and the alert box didn't even pop up.

Comment: Are there [hidden BOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your file?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I had a JS comment above the JSON text in the JSON file.  Once I deleted it, it worked fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `responseText` property refers to a string, containing the response text. It doesn't contain a JavaScript object, and therefore doesn't have a `pageTitle` property.

Since the string is in the JSON format, it can be easily parsed into an object with the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxReq.responseText);
```

Comment: I tried doing JSON.parse(ajaxReq.responseText) and FireBug threw an error saying 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character' and the alert box didn't even pop up.

Comment: The JSON in your question looks fine to me. Can you paste the full JSON straight out of the file into http://jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Nevermind... I had a JS comment above the JSON text in the JSON file. Once I deleted it, it worked fine.

Comment: @Freethinker - Yeah that would cause a problem. Comments are not valid JSON. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score -1):

update `jsonObj = ajaxReq.responseText;` to follow line,please try!

```
jsonObj = eval('(' + ajaxReq.responseText + ')');
```